# Fabric environment variables set in .bashrc are not available

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, deployment, fabric

I'm using Fab to deploy my application. The running of my application depends on some environment variables set in $HOME/.bashrc. However when I use fab to run the application using the below command

```
run("java -jar app.jar")
```

This application does not run as expected because the environment variables like SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT I set in $HOME/.bashrc are not available for this application?

I have set the env variables in $HOME/.bashrc as below

```
export SMTP_PORT=abc
```

How do I ensure the environment variables are set before I execute the run() command to run the app?

Comment: Where are you executing the `run()` command from - the command line? The Python interpreter? Some other program? (Sorry, I'm not that familiar with fabric...)

Comment: Have you tried using this: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html

Comment: This doc does not have any info about the shell environment variables. Why doesn't the java process get the shell environment variables I set in $HOME/.bashrc?

Answer (score 13):

You can find the following lines in `.bashrc`:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

that means fabric will **never** source code after that block, as fabric runs your command **non-interactively** (in form of `/bin/bash -l -c some_command`)

so the simple workaround is moving `export SMTP_PORT=abc` to `.bash_profile` or `.profile`

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Had the same issue and moving the piece of code to the end of `.profile` solved the issue.